# “The glowing redness of the sun“

Tags: phrase-meaning

> ‘the glowing redness of the sun’

https://www.lexico.com/definition/redness

Is it possible to say ‘glowing redness,’ not ‘glowing red’?
I’ve never seen it before. It seems like saying ‘red brightness’ instead of ‘red light’

Comment: Since the dictionary gives it as an example, it is certainly possible!

Comment: Then, is ‘red brightness’ also correct?

Comment: It's _grammatically_ correct, but I don't find it a particularly natural expression. Brightness is a measure of the strength of a source of light, it doesn't have a colour of its own. We would say _bright red light_ or _bright red glow_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with "the glowing red of the sun" is that gerunds can be adjectives, so can colours. If you said "the glowing, red sun" that would be fine - two adjectives, both describing the object 'the sun'.

In your example, 'the sun' isn't the object. A gerund (ie 'glowing') can be an object, as in "I enjoy watching the setting of the sun", rather than "I enjoy watching the sun setting".

"Redness", unlike 'red', can only be a noun, because is a *quality* that the setting sun has. So, in "the glowing redness of the sun", that quality is the object and 'glowing' is an adjective adding detail to it.